# Redirect user to logout (sign-out) page after failing a post-sign-in function

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

We are using MSAL library to authenticate users by Microsoft Azure AD B2C. The following code snippet is from our implementation and it works well in terms of what it's supposed to do (login, logout, etc.)

```js
this.authService.instance.addEventCallback((message: EventMessage) => {
      if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
        this.signInService.signIn();
      } else if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
        this.signOutService.signOut();
      } else if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE) {
          this.logger.log(LogLevel.Error, 'Login failed.');
          if (message.error instanceof AuthError) {
            this.logger.log(LogLevel.Error, 'Authentication error.');
          }
      }
    });
```

As you see in the code, we have a custom implementation `this.signInService.signIn();` to validate the user's data against our database (via a web api) and if the data is found in the database, the user will be able to proceed to use the app.

If the data is not found, we want to sign-out the user, redirect them to the sign-in page probably and intercept them from using the app. How can we achieve this goal?

Please note that the sign-in/sign-up and the sign-out are not custom policies.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There I had approximately the same approach.

You can subscribe to msalBroadcastService and switch to you API request

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
 this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(msg => {
      if (msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS || msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS) {
        return requestToYourDatabase();
      }

      return of(this.authService.signOut())
    })
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    // check here your response from database
    if (!response)
      this.authService.loginRedirect();// Redirect uri should be defined in your MSAL config
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use Angular route guard to protect the routing. You can check your logic inside route guard.

check these article to get more idea.

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

https://codeburst.io/understanding-angular-guards-347b452e1892